# Select/deselect rows in custom table in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table component with checkboxes on each row and on the header. In addition to that, each row has First, Last names and Age that gets rendered from an array of object `dataSet`. I want a way to be able to select/deselect all rows by clicking on the checkbox in the header and capture all the data.

At the same time I also want to be able to select/deselect individual rows. Again, I want to capture the data for each row selected.

Here's the component:

```
class Table extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return( 
            <table style={{width:"100%"}}>
              <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" name="name1" /></th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th> 
                <th>Age</th>
              </tr>
                <tbody>{this.renderRow()}</tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }

    renderRow = () => {
        const dataSet = [
            {
                FirstName: "Bob",
                LastName: "Ross",
                Age: 50
            },
            {
                FirstName: "John",
                LastName: "Doe",
                Age: 20
            },
            {
                FirstName: "Jane",
                LastName: "Doe",
                Age: 30
            }
        ];

        return dataSet.map((item) => {
            return (
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" /></td>
                    <td>{item.FirstName}</td>
                    <td>{item.LastName}</td>
                    <td>{item.Age}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }
};
```

Here's a running version of the component: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/exgeBg

Comment: why the dataSet is declared in `renderRow` ?

Comment: @Vencovsky no real reason, it could just as well be outside.

Comment: is there something missing in the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What have changed:**

First you need to keep the state of the checkboxs, you can set a default value in this part of the code, in case you want some checkbox to start checked:

```
state = {
    header: false,
    fields: [false, false, false, false]
}
```

And now you need the handlers, when some checkBox change.
There is a lot of ways to do this, but to simplify I used two functions
`changeCheckBoxFields` that recives the index of the checkBox to change and `changeAllCheckBox` that change the value of the header's checkbox and all other checkboxs will have the same value as him

Full code running in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MLJQyR)

**Full Code:**

```
class Table extends React.Component {
    state = {
        header: false,
        fields: [],
        dataSet: []
    }

    changeAllCheckBox = () => {
            let {
                header,
                fields,
        } = this.state
        let newHeader = !header
        let newFields = fields.map((f) => {
            return {
                checked: newHeader,
                data: f.data
            }   
        })
        this.setState({
            fields: newFields,
            header: newHeader
        })
    }

    changeCheckBoxFields = (item, index) => {
        let newState = this.state.fields
        newState[index] = {
              check: !newState[index],
              data: item
        }
        this.setState({fields: newState})
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const dataSet = [
            {
                FirstName: "Bob",
                LastName: "Ross",
                Age: 50
            },
            {
                FirstName: "John",
                LastName: "Doe",
                Age: 20
            },
            {
                FirstName: "Jane",
                LastName: "Doe",
                Age: 30
            }
        ];
      let fields = dataSet.map((d, i) => {return {checked: false} } )
      this.setState({
            dataSet: dataSet,
            fields: fields,
      })
    }

    render() {
        return( 
            <table style={{width:"100%"}}>
              <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" name="name1" onChange={this.changeAllCheckBox} /></th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th> 
                <th>Age</th>
              </tr>
                <tbody>{this.renderRow()}</tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }

    renderRow = () => {

        return this.state.dataSet.map((item, index) => {                
            return (
                <tr key={index}>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="name1" onChange={() => this.changeCheckBoxFields(item, index)}  checked={this.state.fields[index].checked} />
                    </td>
                    <td>{item.FirstName}</td>
                    <td>{item.LastName}</td>
                    <td>{item.Age}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }
};
```

For More Information about inputs in react check [Reactjs Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

**Edit:** **CHECK FULL CODE ONLY** Now you can have as many rows as you want, you can get the data and if is checked or not, in the state of the component

Comment: This doesn't give me the row data for the selected item. Also I'm not a fan of `fields: [false, false, false, false]` as I could have a table with a long list of data.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty thats why I asked in your question `why the dataSet is declared in renderRow ?` because if the data can be in your state, its much easier to get the data

Comment: in the actual project the data is stored in global Context.

Comment: For the second point, you could make : `new Array(length).fill(false)` to create your array

Comment: This will generate an array of `[false, false, false, false]` dynamically

Comment: @Treycos I think generating array for each row of data is very inefficient

Comment: It only generates one value for each row of data, in a single array

Answer (score 2):

First, you will need to give each item an `id` of some sort, so you can differentiate them from one another and give them a `key` when mapping them :

```
const dataSet = [
    {
        id: 45612,
        FirstName: "Bob",
        LastName: "Ross",
        Age: 50
    },
    {
        id: 6542,
        FirstName: "John",
        LastName: "Doe",
        Age: 20
    },
    {
        id: 7837,
        FirstName: "Jane",
        LastName: "Doe",
        Age: 30
    }
];
```

Adding the key :

```
return (
    <tr key={item.id}>
```

To know which item is selected, you will need to send the item itself in the `onClick` function of your check box :

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" onClick={this.rowSelected(item)}/></td>
```

The receiving function in your class will be declared as follows and can receive the item, and then the click event :

```
rowSelected = rowData => ev => {
```

The tricky part is now setting the state to contain every selected rows. If the checkbox got check, we will add the item to the previously selected ones, if not, we will filter out the item from the array :

```
rowSelected = rowData => ev => {
    this.setState(prev => ({ 
        selection:  ev.target.checked ? [...prev.selection, rowData] : prev.selection.filter(item => item.id !== rowData.id)
    }))
}
```

You can now access the selected items in `this.state.selection`

Full code :

```
class Table extends React.Component {

    rowSelected = rowData => ev => {
        this.setState(prev => ({ 
            selection:  ev.target.checked ? [...prev.selection, rowData] : prev.selection.filter(item => item.id !== rowData.id)
        }))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <table style={{ width: "100%" }}>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" name="name1" /></th>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>{this.renderRow()}</tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }

    renderRow = () => {
        const dataSet = [
            {
                id: 45612,
                FirstName: "Bob",
                LastName: "Ross",
                Age: 50
            },
            {
                id: 6542,
                FirstName: "John",
                LastName: "Doe",
                Age: 20
            },
            {
                id: 7837,
                FirstName: "Jane",
                LastName: "Doe",
                Age: 30
            }
        ];

        return dataSet.map((item) => {
            return (
                <tr key={item.id}>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" onClick={this.rowSelected(item)}/></td>
                    <td>{item.FirstName}</td>
                    <td>{item.LastName}</td>
                    <td>{item.Age}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }
};
```

---

EDIT

To make a 'select all' button, you will have to make another function :

```
selectAll = ev => {
    this.setState(prev => ({ selction: prev.selection.length ? [] : dataSet }))
}
```

Is the previous selection already has elements in it, it will be emptied, and if it does not have anything, it will be replaced with your entire dataset; which you will need to store somewhere else, like outside of your class or in `this.dataset`.

If you want your checkboxes to be ticked automatically, you will need to set their `checked` props (IIRC) by veryfying if the correspondig item is somwhere in your state :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name1" onClick={this.rowSelected(item)} checked={this.state.selection.some(slc => slc.id === item.id)}/>
```

Comment: In the current version of the code you provide, you don't have the place where he ask for `I want a way to be able to select/deselect all rows by clicking on the checkbox in the header`

Comment: @Vencovsky is right... this gives me the data, but there's no way to select/deselect all rows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'm on the right track. I'm using a custom Checkbox component that has a `Value` prop that returns the clicked/unclicked boolean value. I update it by storing it in state and setting it to setting `Value={this.state.IsSelected}`. Question is, how do I make `IsSelected` only apply to the item selected. Right now it selects/unselects all.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what's going wrong without a bit of code